# reading a resource ends up null

Tags: java, null, inputstream

I have the following code

```
System.out.println("Path::: "+path);
InputStream resource = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Now path is:
src/resources/FF/1-Battle.mp3

This is my folder structure:

```
src 
 |- resources
 |    |- FF
 |    |   |- 1-Battle.mp3
 |- folder
 |    |- prog.java   <- this is the place where the code is run
```

The problem is that resource (The input stream) is ending up null

This needs to work from a jar file so i need it to be relative from the jar file root directoy not the hard disc directory, and hence i cannot create a File since inside a jar file the files are not classifiable under java.io.File

Comment: Can you show your variable `path` please ?

Comment: try changing the path from `src/resources/FF/1-Battle.mp3` to `/src/resources/FF/1-Battle.mp3` i.e start with a slash to indicate that you are searching from the project root directory.

Comment: the root directory needs to be relative, starting with / starts the path from the hard disk root directory and hence i'd need to know the location of the jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just read it using `FileInputStream`? Something like this:-

```
InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
```

and make sure, the path is a proper relative URL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a relative path to where the program is executed? Like '../../resources/FF/1-Battle.mp3"?

Comment: If you do this you can use `File.separator` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to read an mp3 file from within a jar file since the mp3 file is within your src folder. Try this:

```
    try {
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();            
        InputStream resource = cl.getResource("resources/1-battle.mp3").openStream();
    }
    catch(Exception ug) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load mp3 from jar:" + ug.toString());
    }
```